# NullPointerException when using AndroidDriver and calling WebDriverWait

Tags: appium

My code below tries to wait until our native app loads. But it receives NPE:

```
    RemoteWebDriver driver = 
                new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>//this gets NPE below
                //new RemoteWebDriver //this works!!
                (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                    By.xpath("//*[contains(@text, 'Tan')]")));
```

When I replace AndroidDriver with RemoteDriver, everything works as expected! Our app launches and our test code waits until the app loads. The problem is, we cannot use mobile device specific API using RemoteDriver.

Appium GUI v1.4.16.1 (Ophiuchus). Please tell if any other version info is needed, as I'm not good at npm etc. But I downloaded all of the stuff last week.

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:152)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:636)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:369)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:56)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:474)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByXPath(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:134)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByXPath(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByXPath(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:361)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:52)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:895)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:41)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:178)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:238)
```

Here is what I see on Appium GUI:

```
> info: [debug] Appium session started with sessionId 4153c447-cfba-45db-a23a-1e603a3e0e7c
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 17598.310 ms - 74 
> info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/4153c447-cfba-45db-a23a-1e603a3e0e7c {}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"4.4.2","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"app":"C:\\Temp\\appium\\akbank-release.apk","appActivity":"com.akbank.akbankdirekt.ui.prelogin.SplashActivity","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"OJOBUCIBGEKNTKYS"},"app":"C:\\Temp\\appium\\akbank-release.apk","appActivity":"com.akbank.akbankdirekt.ui.prelogin.SplashActivity","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"OJOBUCIBGEKNTKYS"},"sessionId":"4153c447-cfba-45db-a23a-1e603a3e0e7c"}
> info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/4153c447-cfba-45db-a23a-1e603a3e0e7c 200 4.362 ms - 667 {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"4.4.2","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"app":"C:\\Temp\\appium\\akbank-release.apk","appActivity":"com.akbank.akbankdirekt.ui.prelogin.SplashActivity","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"OJOBUCIBGEKNTKYS"},"app":"C:\\Temp\\appium\\akbank-release.apk","appActivity":"com.akbank.akbankdirekt.ui.prelogin.SplashActivity","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"OJOBUCIBGEKNTKYS"},"sessionId":"4153c447-cfba-45db-a23a-1e603a3e0e7c"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/4153c447-cfba-45db-a23a-1e603a3e0e7c/element {"using":"xpath","value":"//*[contains(@text, 'Tan')]"}
> info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@text, 'Tan')]","context":"","multiple":false}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@text, 'Tan')]","context":"","multiple":false}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding //*[contains(@text, 'Tan')] using XPATH with the contextId:  multiple: false
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"Could not find an element using supplied strategy. ","status":7}
> info: [debug] Condition unmet after 8397ms. Timing out.
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":7,"value":{"message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.","origValue":"Could not find an element using supplied strategy. "},"sessionId":"4153c447-cfba-45db-a23a-1e603a3e0e7c"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/4153c447-cfba-45db-a23a-1e603a3e0e7c/element 500 8402.114 ms - 230
```

Comment: Are you trying to automate the browser on android?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977955/how-can-i-use-appium-to-automate-browser-on-android

Comment: No, I'm trying to automate a native app. I tried c'tors new AndroidDriver<MobileElement> or new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> too, they also get NPE.

Comment: What doesn't make sense to me is that you're trying to find an XPATH element that is typically not valid for a native application.  If you're trying to grab an element inside of a webview you need to switch context to that webview and also ensure that it allows to be connected to via chromedriver.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. It is a valid xpath (the code works OK when I switch to RemoteWebDriver). Our app is a native app. I'll add this info to my original post.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more details about the version of appium,  appium GUI, node, npm, web-driver.

Comment: I added the version info I see on Appium GUI. I've read Appium doc again but couldn't find any information on how to determine Appium or npm versions.

Answer (score 0):

I've put a sleep before wait and now I don't get NPE:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = 
            new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>//this gets NPE below
            //new RemoteWebDriver //this works!!
            (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
Thread.sleep(15000);
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                By.xpath("//*[contains(@text, 'Tan')]")));
```

NPE was thrown as soon as the app was first loaded. I think this is an internal Appium problem.

Comment: Did only putting sleep resolved your issue? Because in my case I am still getting same.

Comment: I'm not using Appium anymore, so I can't recreate the problem. But yes, putting the sleep line had resolved my problem. Maybe the versions are different?